# Pygame Font not consistent

Tags: pygame, fonts

I'm working on a program in python+pygame with some other developers, and we're seeing the same font rendered differently. It's a free font that we're distributing with the game. On my machine, this particular font is rendering 10px lower than on another developer's machine.

Any thoughts on why this is?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem but it was when using too different releases of the pygame stuff (especially the truetype library), try to compare the versions of pygame, sdl, sdl-ttf and the freetype library.

Answer (score 0):

> It's a free font that we're distributing with the game.

But whilst you are prototyping and building the program, are you referencing the font file from a local directory within the project, or are you just using the same font, but 'installed' on each machine?

If so, it could be that one machine has a slightly differing version of the font. Try and use the font just from a directory in the project and see if that helps.

Otherwise, it could be some crazy ClearType / TrueType settings or font anti-aliasing or something. I would have no idea how to fix that. Maybe try converting it to a different file format?

Comment: We certainly all have local copies of the font. It was a fairly obscure one, so I don't believe any of us have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

To test: Place a copy of the font the same folder as a python script. 
Or maybe similar font is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame uses te installed fonts on your operating system: maybe you have some different fonts installed or not installed? If so then it will default to a different font than you expect.